# Не могу перенести сайт на yii на OpenServer

Tags: php, yii, openserver, backend

Есть надобность перенести сайт на локалку чтобы поработать с фронтом. 
Сразу скажу сайт я не делал, и в Yii не разбираюсь. 
Всё переношу, получаю ошибки при открытии сайта:

`Warning: include(StructCategory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\YiiBase.php on line 427`

`Warning: include(): Failed opening 'StructCategory.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\modules\translate\models;C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\modules\translate\services;C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\modules\translate\components;C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\services;C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\extensions\extcore;C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\components;C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\models;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.5;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.5/PEAR/pear') in C:\OpenServer\domains\yii\YiiBase.php on line 427`

`Fatal error: Class 'StructCategory' not found in C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\components\CustomComponent.php on line 55`

В чём проблема, как решить?

Comment: проблема в том, что файл `YiiBase.php` пытается подключить файл `StructCategory.php`, но не может его найти. Убедитесь,что файл присутствует в проекте.

Comment: @teran Вообще есть ли, или по тем путям которые в ошибке? По тем путям нет файла, но вообще он лежит в папке `C:\OpenServer\domains\h-astana.dev\protected\modules\struct`

Comment: Попробуй эти файлы перенести в те пути , которые указаны в ошибках